# DATEDIFF between 2 rows aggregating by 2 columns DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a big data set with the structure as shown below.

| Operation | User | Timestamp | Elapsed time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | 2018-01-03 | 11:19:02 AM |
| 12 | 1 | 2018-01-03 | 12:34:02 PM |
| 12 | 1 | 2018-01-04 | 8:34:02 AM |
| 12 | 2 | 2018-02-03 | 9:34:02 AM |
| 12 | 2 | 2018-02-03 | 11:12:42 AM |
| 12 | 3 | 2018-02-03 | 12:12:00 PM |
| 15 | 1 | 2018-01-02 | 9:22:32 AM |
| 15 | 1 | 2018-01-02 | 9:25:32 AM |
| 15 | 2 | 2018-01-02 | 9:25:32 AM |

The goal is to form the column "Elapsed Time" using DAX and PowerBI. The column shows the difference/duration between the current timestamp and previous timestamp for the same user and the same operation.

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
Elapsed time =
DATEDIFF (
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( data[Timestamp] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( data, data[Operation], data[User] ),
        data[Timestamp] < EARLIER ( data[Timestamp] )
    ),
    data[Timestamp],
    MINUTE
)
```

`

But it complains about `a single value for column 'Timestamp' in table 'data' cannot be determined. this can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregator such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.`

I'm very new to DAX, so I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Since the  `'Table'[Operation]` and `'Table'[User]` of the current row are to be used as filter, a very simple approach might just use CALCULATE to trigger the context transition, transforming the current row context to the corresponding filter context, and then to replace the filer over `'Table'[Timestamp]` to be less than the current Timestamp, previously saved to a variable. The context transition automatically sets the correct filters over `'Table'[Operation]` and `'Table'[User]`

```
Elapsed time =
VAR CurrentTimestamp = 'Table'[TimeStamp]
RETURN
    DATEDIFF (
        CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Timestamp] ), 'Table'[Timestamp] < CurrentTimestamp ),
        CurrentTimestamp,
        MINUTE
    )
```

Comment: His requirement was a column though, so there are no filters in calculated columns

Comment: Yes, there are after the context transition inside CALCULATE and they correspond to the current row for which the calculated column is evaluated :)

Comment: I hope my answer is clearer now. Thank you for showing that it wasn't clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Typing on the mobile, so apologies for possible errors. Assuming this is a calculated column:

```
Elapsed time =
DATEDIFF (
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Table[Timestamp] ),
        FILTER (
            Table,
            Table[User] = EARLIER ( Table[User] )
                && Table[Operation] = EARLIER ( Table[Operation] )
                && Table[Timestamp] < EARLIER ( Table[Timestamp] )
        )
    ),
    Table[Timestamp],
    MINUTE
)
```

Where Table is your table name.

There surely are now ways to do that, do apologies for non optimal approach.